# Relative Path instead of Absolute paths in Excel VBA

Tags: vba, excel

The following code is working fine but now if I want it to give my colleagues I need to use a relative path for getting a workbook in the code:

```
Sub HELLO()

Dim x As Workbook


Sheets("Sheet1").Cells.Clear

'## Open both workbooks first:
Set x = Workbooks.Open("C:\Users\500722\Desktop\dashboard\Task.xls")


'Now, transfer values from x to y:
Sheet1.Cells(1, 1) = x.Sheets("Page 1").Range("A1")
With x.Sheets("Page 1").UsedRange
    'Now, paste to y worksheet:
    Sheet1.Range("A1").Resize( _
        .Rows.Count, .Columns.Count) = .Value

End With

x.Close

End Sub
```

If I use give `Set x = Workbooks.Open("\Task.xls")` I get an error saying the path couldn't be found.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Use this instead:

```
Set x = Workbooks.Open(ThisWorkbook.Path & "\Task.xls")
```

Answer (score 3):

A different view of your question - Macro Mans answer does give the path relative to the workbook.

Your example code is referencing the users desktop, so I'm guessing that may be the path you're after - the path relative to the user.

```
'Special folders are : AllUsersDesktop, AllUsersStartMenu
'AllUsersPrograms, AllUsersStartup, Desktop, Favorites
'Fonts, MyDocuments, NetHood, PrintHood, Programs, Recent
'SendTo, StartMenu, Startup, Templates
Public Sub Test()
    Dim oShell As Object
    Set oShell = CreateObject("WScript.Shell")
    MsgBox oShell.SpecialFolders("Desktop")
End Sub
```

There's plenty of sites that give this info if you search for `SpecialFolders VBA`.
http://www.rondebruin.nl/win/s3/win027.htm
https://bytes.com/topic/access/insights/933853-find-users-special-folders-such-desktop-my-documents

Comment: Another option is `Environ$("USERPROFILE") & "\Desktop\"` if you want the desktop :)